# Alert running twice in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My alert for an invalid login is running twice in my react project and I cant figure out why. Upon authenticating with the server side, I will get a response true or false and set it to userLogin.

```
const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState(null);
 
  function handleAlert() {
    alert("Invalid Login, Please Try Again.");
    document.getElementById("username").value = "";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "";
  }
```

This is my JSX

```
{userLogin == false && userLogin !== null
          ? (handleAlert(), setUserLogin(null))
          : null}
```

I have tried putting an arrow function before calling it, but it completely stops working. Can anyone help from it running twice? Thanks

Comment: Can we have more code to understand ? I guess your components is rendering twice for some reasons but I can't figured it with just this piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the double alert will be that some props or state is changing, causing your component to rerender. When that happens, all the code in your function component is ran - including the ternary expression inside your JSX return value.

Calling functions which cause side effects (here `alert` is a side effect, as is `setUserLogin`) in code which is supposed to be simply concerned with what to render is fundamentally wrong. When you need some side effects to be ran if certain conditions hold, you need to use the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) Hook.

In your case, you can simply remove this from your return value (as it never actually renders anything):

```
{userLogin == false && userLogin !== null
      ? (handleAlert(), setUserLogin(null))
      : null}
```

and instead put this in the main body of your function component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userLogin == false && userLogin !== null) {
    handleAlert();
    setUserLogin(null);
  } 
}, [userLogin]);
```

Side note: you probably don't want to check `userLogin == false`, it behaves very strangely. In general, consider using `===` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your component is rerendering twice before the state changes,
i would suggest using a useEffect to run whatever code you have inside the handleAlert, and have that useEffect to depend on "userLogin",

Something like

```
useEffect( () => {
   if(userLogin == false && userLogin !== null){
      alert("Invalid Login, Please Try Again.");
      document.getElementById("username").value = "";
      document.getElementById("password").value = "";
   }
},[userLogin]);
```

This way you are 100% sure that the code will only run when userLogin changes
Hope this works for you